# PySpark - split the string column and join part of them to form new columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with following format:

```
id    text
1     Amy How are you today? Smile
2     Sam Not very well. Sad
```

I want to generate a new frame with following format:

```
id    Name    Content              Expression
1     Amy     How are you today?   Smile
2     Sam     Not very well.       Sad
```

To do so, I plan to first split the text column:

```py
cols = F.split(df['text'], ' ')
df = df.withColumn('Name', cols.getItem(0))
```

But how do I get content and expression? Can I use `cols.getItem(-1)` to get last element of the text? And how do I join the cols[1:-1] (second element to last second element) in `cols` to form the new column `content`?

---

I investigate the data actually the double quotes with the sentence are not guaranteed. The only thing can rely on it is the space split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given input *dataframe* with schema as

```
+---+----------------------------+
|id |text                        |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |Amy How are you today? Smile|
|2  |Sam Not very well. Sad      |
+---+----------------------------+
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

You can simply use following `udf` function to get your requirement fulfilled

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t

@f.udf(t.StructType([t.StructField("Name", t.StringType(), True), t.StructField("Content", t.StringType(), True), t.StructField("Expression", t.StringType(), True)]))
def splitCols(array):
    return (array[0], ' '.join(array[1:len(array)-1]), array[len(array)-1])

df.withColumn('text', splitCols(f.split('text', ' ')))\
    .select(f.col('id'), f.col('text.*'))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+------------------+----------+
|id |Name|Content           |Expression|
+---+----+------------------+----------+
|1  |Amy |How are you today?|Smile     |
|2  |Sam |Not very well.    |Sad       |
+---+----+------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be cleaner to just make a UDF to do this. But you can also pull this off with just [Spark functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html).

```
df\
    .withColumn("Name", split(col("text"), " ").getItem(0))\
    .withColumn("Content", regexp_extract(col("text"), "[a-zA-Z0-9]+ (.*) [a-zA-Z0-9]+", 1)) \
    .withColumn("Expression", reverse(split(reverse(col("text")), " ").getItem(0))) \
    .show()


.+---+--------------------+----+------------------+----------+
| id|                text|Name|           Content|Expression|
+---+--------------------+----+------------------+----------+
|  1|Amy How are you t...| Amy|How are you today?|     Smile|
|  2|Sam Not very well...| Sam|    Not very well.|       Sad|
+---+--------------------+----+------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spltText = udf(lambda data:[ele.strip() for ele in data.split('"')], ArrayType(StringType()))
spltDF = df.withColumn("spltData",spltText(df.text))
spltDF = (spltDF.withColumn('Name', spltDF.spltData.getItem(0))
                .withColumn('Content', spltDF.spltData.getItem(1))
                .withColumn('Expression', spltDF.spltData.getItem(2)))
spltDF.select('id','Name','Content','Expression').show()

+---+----+------------------+----------+
| id|Name|           Content|Expression|
+---+----+------------------+----------+
|  1| Amy|How are you today?|   (Smile)|
|  2| Sam|    Not very well.|     (Sad)|
+---+----+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hi sorry I re-investigate the data actually the double quotes with the sentence are not guaranteed. The only thing can rely on it is the space split. How do I do that? Thanks!